# Using variables from previous maven phases

Tags: java, maven, testng

I created a mojo intended to just run test cases. In the `compile` phase of my mojo, the only thing I do is to obtain a list of paths for running dynamic tests with TestNG. However when the test phase is reached, the list has no longer anything inside it.

Should I move my mojo's goal execution to another phase? How should be this implementation?

Comment: so your mojo is actually replacing surefire:test?

Comment: Unclear. Please read [ask] and explain more precisely your use-case.

Comment: No, it's not. In fact, its only goal is to obtain the list I mentioned.

Comment: The list of paths ? For what is that needed ?

Answer (score 1):

My advice is that you keep phases atomic.  If you need that list of paths in compile phase and another phase as well, then you should retrieve it both times.  You shouldn't depend on another phase because you're not guaranteed that it even ran.

If this task is particularly arduous, then if nothing else you could consider serializing the results to a file that would be read from if it exists from all phases that would require it.  However, if it isn't arduous, just recalculate it.